# JavaScript function with PHP variable as parameter

Tags: javascript, php, function

I've searched about escaping the parameter inside the JS function and I've tried lots of suggestions but none works. Here is the code:

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="delete('.$fetch['bicc'].')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</a>'
```

I always get this error:

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
delete(123456789_7_ZY7)
```

Comment: your param is a string type , you have to add quotes

Comment: You can find a solution below. You forgot about `"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes, your param is a string type :

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="delete(\''.$fetch['bicc'].'\')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about `\"`

```
onClick="delete(\"'.$fetch['bicc'].'\")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</a>
```

So it should be like:

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="delete(\"'.$fetch['bicc'].'\")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, if you want to use PHP variables in your JavaScript code, you need to wrap them in [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="delete('.json_encode($fetch['bicc']).')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</a>'
```

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is able to take most PHP variables (strings, arrays, associative arrays) and correctly encode them as their JavaScript counterparts (e.g., adding quotes for strings).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a quote since the parameter is a string

```
echo "<a class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\" onclick=\"delete(\"${fetch['bicc']}\")\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span> Remove</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

$fetch['bicc'] has string type value?

if yes:

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="delete(\"'.$fetch['bicc'].'\")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</a>'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = str_replace('_', ' ', $fetch['bicc']);
echo '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="delete('.$data.')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</a>'
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, try to explain your answer